# Python - Selenium webdriver timeout exception error

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, timeoutexception

my goal is to access the IMDB site from a different website and try to get movie genres.

I can do this when I use the direct Xpath of the IMDB button on the website I redirected.
`driver.get("http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0118564/")`

However, when I do it in the code I want to use for a loop, it gives a TimeoutException error.

```
i = 3

driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/div/div[2]/div[1]/p[{}]/a".format(i)).click()
driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/div/div[2]/div[1]/p[1]/a").click()
```

What am I doing wrong?

**NOTE:** IMDB page of the movie genres I want to get: https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0118564/

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
import time
import selenium.common.exceptions as selexcept
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

genres0, genres1, genres2, genres3 = "","","",""

driver = webdriver.Chrome()


driver.get("https://sfy.ru/scripts") # main website


#driver.get("http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0118564/") # website for genres


i = 3

driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/div/div[2]/div[1]/p[{}]/a".format(i)).click()
driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/div/div[2]/div[1]/p[1]/a").click()


genres = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH, "//h4[.='Genres:']/following-sibling::a")))
print(", ".join([genre.text for genre in genres]))



print(genres)
```

ERROR:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TimeoutException                          Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-62-ff9c6618ff0f> in <module>
     25 
     26 
---> 27 genres1 = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//*[@id='titleStoryLine']/div[4]/a[1]"))).text
     28 genres2 = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//*[@id='titleStoryLine']/div[4]/a[2]"))).text
     29 genres3 = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//*[@id='titleStoryLine']/div[4]/a[3]"))).text

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\support\wait.py in until(self, method, message)
     78             if time.time() > end_time:
     79                 break
---> 80         raise TimeoutException(message, screen, stacktrace)
     81 
     82     def until_not(self, method, message=''):

TimeoutException: Message:
```